# How to install sqlite3 database tables to run with a Django project?

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I'm reading a tutorial on how to build a web application with Django. So far, I have installed Django and it seems to work find.

The tutorial asked to create project folders by typing (in Windows command prompt):

```
django-admin.py startproject django_bookmarks
```

The folders and files were created successfully. See below:

```
django_bookmarks/
__init__.py
manage.py
settings.py
urls.py
```

Then it says we can work with SQLite3 for now (later when we deploy we will need larger
database engine such as MySQL.
Then I had to setup the database in engine by running settings.py.
and make sure codes are written as follow:

```
DATABASE_ENGINE = 'sqlite3'
DATABASE_NAME = 'bookmarksdb'
DATABASE_USER = ''
DATABASE_PASSWORD = ''
DATABASE_HOST = ''
DATABASE_PORT = ''
```

I made the changes above.
Here comes the bad stuff.  I need to create database tables that the application will run 
with by typing (in Windows command prompt):

```
python manage.py syncdb
```

then I get an error message saying the following:

```
"load_backend raise ImproperlyConfigured(error_msg)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured:'sqlite3 isn't an available database
backend.
Try using django.db.backends.sqlite3 instead.
Error was: No module named base"
```

Now, how can I setup those needed sqlite3 database tables?
Any help will do, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The database engine needs to be set to django.db.backends.sqlite3

```
DATABASE_ENGINE = 'django.db.backends.sqlite3'
DATABASE_NAME = 'bookmarksdb'
DATABASE_USER = ''
DATABASE_PASSWORD = ''
DATABASE_HOST = ''
DATABASE_PORT = ''
```

More recent versions of Django (post 1.3) require this to be fully specified. If you're following a book or guide it may refer to an older Django version.

Comment: I didn't get it in the first place. Set the engine, set the engine.. OK too many hours of thinking in a row is the excuse :-D Thanks!

Comment: No problem at all. I have updated my answer, I hope it is clearer now.

Comment: Thanks~! it's crystal clear. It created the database tables properly. Cheers!